# Opamp output clamp

Tags: operational-amplifier, protection, precision

During power-up, U2A's voltage will be undefined. I would therefore like to clamp it with a relay. Additionally, U2A is buffering a voltage from a 20-bit DAC -- therefore I need to care about thermal EMF. This means I can't pass the voltage through a relay, but crowbarring it with one is ok since once open it won't be in the signal path. In this design, I use a normally closed relay which is opened when power has stabilized. There is an issue that ANY offset voltage on U2A's + pin, or internal to U2A will be amplified by the open loop gain. This will likely make U2A rail when clamped. When the relay opens, the voltage will swing wildly at the output as the opamp recovers, which is unacceptable.

Is there any way to ensure that when the clamping relay opens, pin 1 on U2A is within a fraction of a millivolt of ground? I'm curious if this is possible without interrupting the signal path between U2A and J?. There are of course solid state relays (CotoMOS), latching relays, and ultra low EMF relays -- I'm just curious if it's possible to do without.

I also do not want to add any additional impedances in the signal path, such as resistors. I want to retain the low output impedance of U2A

[image: Schematic]

Answer (score 1):

You could attach a window comparator to the output of U2A, however I don't think that will give you what you want.

When the feedback is shorted to ground the output of U2A will probably be railed at one or the other extreme since you've shorted out the negative feedback. The op-amp has a typical gain of about 4E6 and a *typical* offset voltage of +/-5uV so even if the input was exactly at 0V you'd have it attempting +/-20V at the output. Worst case is almost 10x worse.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly my worry. Is there any way around it? I guess one has to either use an opamp with a shutdown pin, or stick a switch in the signal path.

Comment: Not really sure exactly what you are trying to do. Maybe add a series resistor to the non-inverting input and short the output to non-inverting input with another relay contact. But unless you are looking at a lot less than a fraction of a mV that seems excessive.

Comment: I'm super confused. What's excessive about this scheme? It seems like by clamping the output to the input you're just forcing the opamp to see it's offset voltage, and so it will still rail.

Comment: The worry about thermal EMFs seems excessive if you are just looking at a (sizable) fraction of a mV, which is a relatively large voltage.

Comment: Oh no. I'm worried about a microvolt due to thermal EMF. The fraction of a mV is what I'm willing to accept as a transient on J?-1 when opening the relay.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. Issues like charge injection might come up, but this is already too long a comment chain and way off the original question.

Comment: Also -- adding this relay doesn't circumvent the input offset issue, does it? You've forced + and - to be equal but the output will swing to try and make these equal to the input offset voltage, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135392/discussion-between-evan-and-spehro-pefhany).

Answer (score 1):

- you can clamp the input to 0V with a series R and shunt FET to any ratio you need using a power on reset (POR) pulse to gate since Zin+ is high.

  - E.g. 10k source to 1 ohm FET is 80 dB attenuation of input.
- The open loop reduces the output offset by the feedback gain = Aol for Acl=1 contrary to your assumption
- The output impedance also is reduced by Rout/Aol(f) , which is reduces with rising f from internal integration. Since Op Amps have internal current limiting, 330R is redundant.
- Ii and Iio are input current specs that can add to Vio if source resistors for Vi+,Vi- are not matched and create offset Ii*Rdelta, so choose same R impedances for both inputs.

Comment: When the opamp is crowbarred, there's no feedback whatsoever, and presumably the opamp will try it's hardest to force +/- to be equal to the input offset voltage by dumping it's full output current into the output pin. I'm just concerned about the recovery behavior from this, since as you open the relay, that current will be temporarily diverted into J?-1